# rake db:setup shows rake aborted! KeyError: key not found: "URL_HOST" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

i have rails app ubuntu 18.04. bundle install run successful but when i run rake db:setup it shows

rake aborted!
KeyError: key not found: "URL_HOST"
/var/www/myapp/code/config/environments/production.rb:71:in `fetch'
/var/www/myapp/code/config/environments/production.rb:71:in`block in '
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in`configure'
/var/www/myapp/code/config/environments/production.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in`block (2 levels) in '
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `each'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in`block in '
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in`each'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/www/myapp/code/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in`block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`eval'
/home/myappuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Need help

Comment: Can we see the contents of your /var/www/myapp/code/config/environments/production.rb:71. From what it appears, you may need to provide the `URL_HOST` environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some config settings for URL_HOST is missing.